# Socket programming does not connect in real android device

Tags: java, android, sockets

I want to send data(simple text) from android to computer and show received text in computer application, for that reason i created 2 applications which first one run in android device(client) and second one run in computer(server). i have created both applications with java language.

when i run android application in genymotion, everything is ok and both applications could connect together but when i run android application in real device applications cannot connect together while both are in same network and ip address is correct. 
codes for computer application(server):

```
try {
     ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(9000);
     Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

     DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

     while(true){
         String message = bufferedReader.readLine();
         message(message);
     }
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

codes for android application(Client):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                message("Waiting for Connection...");
                socket= new Socket("192.168.1.6", 9000);
                message("Connected...");

                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(socket==null){ return; }

            try {
                String message = edtMessage.getText().toString() + "\n";
                dataOutputStream.write(message.getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
         message(message);
     }
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[screen shot(application connected when i run android application in genymotion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkL1Q.png)

please guide me for resolve that issue. Thanks

Comment: If 192.168.1.6 is the ip address of the computer where your server is running and the device is in the same network and it does not work then very often the firewall is preventing connection. Switch it off to try. You forgot to tell which error/exception you get now.

Comment: Yes computer is 192.168.1.6 and both devices are in same network. I turned of firewall even i exited antivirus(kaspersky total security) but i have same issue. it throws IOException

Comment: You catch IOException twice. Which one? What does e.getMessage() say? Else post the stacktrace.

Comment: first IOException. says: failed to connect to /192.168.1.6 (port 9000): connect failed: EHOSTUNREACH (No route to host)

Comment: Your server programm can only accept one client. How do you stop it? Did you restart it?

Comment: yes, first cancel it and then open it again

Comment: no body can guide me?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write to the output stream in the handler of an on click listener. You should do that in a thread too.

Comment: application works in genymotion correctly, but in real device cannot connect to server.

Comment: Yes you said that before. We already know. Now put your code in a thread.

Comment: i did, but i have same issue :( is there another way for connecting android to pc?